# dynamic_cast vs static_cast to void*

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers, dynamic-cast

In the last two lines of below program, `static_cast<void*>` and `dynamic_cast<void *>` behave differently. From what I understand, The result of a `dynamic_cast<void*>` always resolves to the address of the complete object. So it uses RTTI in some way. Could anyone explain how compilers uses RTTI to differentiate between the two.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Top {
protected:
int x;
public:
    Top(int n) { x = n; }
    virtual ~Top() {} 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Top& t) {
        return os << t.x;
    }
};
class Left : virtual public Top {
protected:
    int y;
public:
    Left(int m, int n) : Top(m) { y = n; }
};
class Right : virtual public Top {
protected:
    int z;
public:
    Right(int m, int n) : Top(m) { z = n; }
};
class Bottom : public Left, public Right {
    int w; 
public:
    Bottom(int i, int j, int k, int m): Top(i), Left(0, j), Right(0, k) { w = m; }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Bottom& b) {
        return os << b.x << ',' << b.y << ',' << b.z<< ',' << b.w;
    }
};
int main() {
    Bottom b(1, 2, 3, 4);
    cout << sizeof b << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << static_cast<void*>(&b) << endl;
    Top* p = static_cast<Top*>(&b);
    cout << *p << endl;
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << endl;
    cout << dynamic_cast<void*>(p) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output: https://ideone.com/WoX5DI

```
28
1,2,3,4
0xbfcce604
1
0xbfcce618
0xbfcce618
0xbfcce604
```

Comment: Dynamic cast to `void*` works the same way as dynamic cast to derived class pointer. In the typical implementation it looks up the vptr of the object pointed to by the pointer and uses that to determine the type of the most derived object. The offset can then be calculated accordingly.

Comment: @Brian That is impossible in the void* case

Comment: `dynamic_cast<void*>` - does it even make sense to do? Every code that does it should fail any decent review.

Comment: @BЈовић: `dynamic_cast` to `void *` is a dedicated, specific feature of `dynamic_cast` designed that way on purpose. I never used it in practice, but apparently someone thought it made practical sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From 5.2.7 / 7:

> If T is "pointer to cv void," then the result is a pointer to the most
>   derived object pointed to by v. Otherwise, a run-time check is applied
>   to see if the object pointed or referred to by v can be converted to
>   the type pointed or referred to by T.

So using `dynamic_cast<void*>(o)` you get a pointer to the first byte of the most "derived" object (if `o` is polymorphic).

The code the compiler generates for `dynamic_cast<void *>(...)` is something like:

```
static_cast<void*>(dynamic_cast<most_derived_type *>(...))
```

This property is often used for serialization.

Comment: C++ is full of surprises.

Comment: This is (also) useful for pointer comparisons to establish object identity, especially when there is (non-`virtual`) diamond inheritance.